# Execute MS SQL stored procedure upon DTMF selection in PHPAGI

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, asterisk, agi

I am trying to run a stored procedure from ms sql server after user dtmf tone in PHPAGI, however it seems that the SP is never triggered. Any ideas or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Required:

```
$press1 = $agi->get_data('please-select-menu',300, 1);
$press1dtmf = $press1['result'];
if ($press1dtmf=="1"){
//run ms sql stored procedure;  
$agi->stream_file('thank-you');
$agi->hangup();
```

Tried & Not Working Method:

```
$press1 = $agi->get_data('please-select-menu',300, 1);
$press1dtmf = $press1['result'];
if ($press1dtmf=="1"){
$sql_statement =  mssql_init("sp_name '$value1' ,'$value2', '$value3'", $conn);
$result=mssql_execute($sql_statement);
mssql_free_statement($sql_statement);
$agi->stream_file('thank-you');
$agi->hangup();
}
```

Comment: This have no any relation to AGI/asterisk. Check why you php code can't trigger sql.

Comment: I understand that you mean to say that I should debug my PHP code. But this SP is running fine from a PHP web page. 

I have 2 SP running on this same page and this is the 3rd one, this one isnt triggered tho.

Comment: Check that it work ok under asterisk user,statment is correct(put statment back via Verbose/Noop), check that all path are correct(full). There are no any way fix somethign based on code you provided.

Comment: I have 2 other stored procedures on same PHPAGI script, if I comment any one of those and then try this DTMF then its workin fine with Asterisk, upon DTMF selection the stored procedure is executed. However this doesnt work if any of the previous SP are not commented. Pretty strange :/ Seems something to do with mssql_free_statement($sql_statement2); have also done this for both previous SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mssql_free_result($result);
```

added the above to the code and everthing worked!